# The import android.print cannot be resolved

Tags: android, printing, sdk

i am trying to implement print function inside my app. but it gives me  `PrintManager cannot be resolved to a type` error

Minimum requirement for that class **android.print.PrintManager** was API 19. i tried changing my `minSdkVersion` to 19 as well. but not working

**NOTE:** I have updated SDK Platform for API 19 in my sdk.

is there something i should update seperately in sdk for this to work? or is there seperate library to be added in my project?

Comment: Right click project--->properties--->android--->Make sure project build target is 19.

Comment: thanx man it worked. i dont know why i didnt think of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click project--->Properties--->android--->Set your project build target to 19.

Clean and rebuild and it will work.